# How to make drupal module compatible to resolve the error ".zip or tar.gz does not contain any .info.yml files"

Tags: drupal, error-handling, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-8

I worked on the following Drupal versions,

1. Drupal 7.5
2. Drupal 8.2

While working on Drupal 7.5, I never faced a problem while installing the following modules,

1. Form Module
2. Poll Module
3. Pane Module

But, now when I have started a new website on localhost with Drupal 8.2, the following modules are showing issues while trying to install. Maybe the issue is because these modules aren't compatible/ updated with the new Drupal 8.2. These modules are now showing the following error while uploading and trying to install in Drupal 8.2,

```
"module name".zip or tar.gz does not contain any .info.yml files"
```

What we can do in that case? I want the above modules to work in Drupal 8.2 as well.

Answer (score 0):

which form module did you try? drupal 8 core provides the contact form. you dont need a module for this. (https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/contact/overview)

the poll module has a drupal 8 port. are you sure you downloaded the latest version for drupal 8? (https://www.drupal.org/project/poll)

and finally the pane module is depricated in drupal 8. i think there comes your error because in the pane module is no module.info.yml.

you should try the panels module for drupal 8. (https://www.drupal.org/project/panels) or if you want to write modules yourself read something like here (https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules). its a bit more difficult because of the OOP, controller and routing.